# Understanding what happens with Raspberry Pi Pico in idle

Tags: pi-pico, power-management

I am verry new to Pico and I want to understand something. This is just a microcontroler, not a mini computer like RPi 4. From what I study so far, they say that it has a 125 MHz fixed clock and it doesn't lower the clock frequency when idle, like RPi 4 does when I execute a `time.sleep()` function and is idle. What should I do in Pico when my MicroPython script got nothing to do and waits for something from the user ? Should I make an infinite loop `while True: pass` or should I call the `time.sleep()` too ? I mean, is there a difference between them in terms of power consumption ? Will the Pico runs hoter in the infinite loop ? I don't want to put the Pico in low power mode, because I need it to be active and ready to take commands. But sometimes it got nothing to do...

Comment: There are several techniques available for reducing the Pico's power consumption when idle. What have you tried searching so far - perhaps in the "Official Documentation"???

Answer (score 0):

This Question is unanswerable because you haven't said **what you are trying to do** (or what you are attempting to achieve).

The simple answer is **it depends** - choosing an appropriate algorithm is *the art of computer programming*.

If you are waiting for a single input - **use a blocking command** and let the compiler do the work.

In general idle loops are poor practice.